# ¿Como controlar el tiempo de redireccion al clickear en un elemento a?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Creando una pagina web me surgió un problema. Con *jquery* implemente cambios de CSS.

En resumen es una imagen dentro de un `<a>` (enlace a una pagina interna). La idea es que al dar clic sobre la imagen el tamaño aumente y se oscurece todo lo restante visible a exepcion de la imagen. Lo anterior dicho lo logre pero no es apreciado ya que al dar clic la dirección a la pagina interna es muy rápido. Mi pregunta es,

¿Como puedo determinar un tiempo posterior al click sobre a para así ver el efecto del CSS modificado?

Busque y encontré que seria con el método `setTimeout()`, pero no logro dar con el código correcto. Disculpen la ignorancia sobre el tema y si no me exprese correctamente. Gracias :)

PD: acepto correcciones de todo tipo, estoy empezando en esto.

Code JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    'use strict';

    // Superior a 1400px
    if($("body").width() >= 1400){
      
        // Aumentar imagen al dar click en a
        $('.img-prota').click(function(){
            $(this).css({"transform": "scale(1.1)"});
            $('img').not(this).fadeTo("fast",0.50,"swing");//Desaparece en un tiempo determinado
            $(this).html();
        });
        
        // Cambiar de color al pasar puntero por a
        $('.img-prota').on({
            click:function(){
                $(".letras").css({"color":"#dd0a0f", "transition": "0.6s ease-in-out all"});
            },
            mouseenter:function(){
                $(".letras").css({"color":"white", "transition": "0.6s ease-in-out all"});
            },
            mouseleave:function(){
                $(".letras").css({"color":"#212529", "transition": "0.6s ease-in-out all"});
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes valerte de:

- El [método `preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para que el navegador no vaya inmediatamente al destino del *link*, que seria el proceso normal de un *link* y en esta ocación lo haremos *manualmente* más adelante.
- Un timer, mediante `setTimeout()` para, un tiempo después, realizar la acción e ir al destino de dicho *link*.

El ejemplo a continuación demora intencionalmente 2 segundos antes de procesar el vínculo, mientras que hace parte de tus efectos visuales en el resto de `<a>`'s presentes.

```js
$(function(){
    $("a").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.location.href = link;
        }, 2000);

        $('a').not(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.15, "swing");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/447427/21">Mi respuesta a tu pregunta</a><br />
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/447404/21">Tu pregunta</a><br />
<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">es.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: Mil gracias! Muy claro explicado :)

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo crear una función con lo que ya tienes y de ese modo la invocas dentro de este otro código, reemplazando el alert que yo te he dejado.

```js
function myFunction() {
  setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hola"); }, 3000);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Al darle click al botón, pasarán 3 segundos y se ejecutará el Alert.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Presiona aquí</button>

</body>
</html>
```